# Login link with current page passed as query string that then uses it to send user back

Tags: cakephp

How would I create a login link on a CakePHP page that contains a query string with the current page so for example: `domain.com/login/?back=/posts/This_is_a_post`

and then how would I use this in the `login` method to send the user BACK to this url?

I have tried this: `<?php echo $this->Html->link('Log in', array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login','admin'=>false, '?'=> array('back'=>$this->here)), array('escape'=>false)); ?>`

but it does this on the url `/login?back=%2Fportfolio%2Fgt%2FCreatHive`

how do I get it to NOT change the `/` in the URL

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to store the last page visited in a session at some point, probably when the page is loaded in the `login`  action or something. Why you ask? As an attacked could make a link to your site eg: `yoursite.com/login?back=mysite.com/login`, so that when the user logs in, you send them to *my site which is an exact duplicate of your login form* and get them to login again. Voila, an attacker could now easily phish your users info.

With sessions there'd be no url encoding problems either. Just something like this in your `login` action:

```
$this->Session->set('back_to', $this->referer());

// Then if they have logged in:
$backTo = $this->Session->read('back_to');
if($backTo) {
    $this->redirect($back_to);
} else {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update - Try using named parameters instead:

For your link:

```
echo $this->Html->link('My Link', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'url' => $url));
```

In your users login:

```
function login(){
    if($this->Session->read('Auth.User')){
        $url = $this->params['named']['url']
        // encode/decode url
        $this->redirect("$url");
    }
}
```

You can always use urlencode() and urldecode() for the $url variable.

You also need to make sure your form also sends the URL back to the login function:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'url' => $url));
```

Comment: Hi I didn't ask how to create a login form. I asked how to create a link with a query string :)

Comment: I just get the link but no query string?

Comment: Just checked http://api.cakephp.org/class/auth-component#method-AuthComponentlogin - you can't pass anything other than login post data to the login method. So try using $this->params['named'] instead?

Comment: So I can't use query strings with the login method at all?

Comment: I just tried - you can access your url using $this->params['named']['url'] inside the login action if you made a link as described above. Bear in mind you'll have to set your form action to the link as well.

Comment: What about the query string though?

Comment: You can set $url to anything you want really; and if it's being difficult just use urlencode() / urldecode().

Comment: Yeah but I WANT to use a query string rather than a named parameter though but I don't want it to mess up the URL like it is doing. I've tried using both urlencode and urldecode but the URL is still messed up?